# Is there a way to roll back to a previous date?

Tags: sandbox, setup

The sys admin who created our setup is on extended leave, and she changed something bf she left and now new users can't save any accounts or contacts they create. I would like to either roll back to before she left, or replace Prod with the Sandbox setup. Are either of these options possible? I have very little experience with SF, but have to take over her job for now. Thanks!

Comment: Rollback - not possible out of the box unless you had implemented [Backup and Restore](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=backup_restore.htm&type=5&language=en_US) or an equivalent 3rd party solution.  Replace Prod with Sandbox - possible via a 3rd party tool. Out of the box, you'd have a hard time doing this manually. Either option is not a good idea in your situation. Call your Salesforce account manager and ask them to recommend a consulting company to help you. You can also try opening a case with SF support, they might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

@identigral's comments are spot-on but you might be able to get away with a "fix" by going to `Setup | View Setup Audit Log` and inspecting what specific changes were made to the PROD config by your on-leave sysadmin.

This will help focus on what needs to be rolled back where such rollback could be done via a simple Changeset from Sandbox or (horrors) direct update in PROD.

That is, the inability to save new Accounts and Contacts could be due to a simple config change rather than (and hopefully not), a deep and complex Apex change.

If you discover that there were systemic changes made (a big release) by your sysad, then my suggestion is not practical.

It is of course possible that your sysad used a tool like Gearset or Copado to do the deployment and those tools come with OOTB rollback (but you'd need to be a user of those products)

Comment: +1; another facet this problem is highlighting is a complete lack of change management or ticketing for this org, to which tools like Gearset and Copado are one solution.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that new users can't see a required custom field and it's triggering an error in a junction object flow. This doesn't happen when I create new users in the Sandbox -- she hasn't touched the Sandbox bf leaving. I have to.figure out what controls who sees this field - I tried making it not be required, but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how to get up to speed as a sys admin? Thank you to all who commented, much appreciated

Comment: As suggested, I checked the audit log but can't see how the changes she's made would have affected this issue.

Comment: My suggestion based on your comment is to look at the user's Profile and see if they have read/edit access to the field in question on the object(s) in question